# C# wpf Geração de dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Tenho um dataGrid que esta sendo gerado automaticamente

```
dgPagamentos.ItemsSource = HistoricoDoClienteViewModel.ExibirPagamentosPorCliente(id);
```

Meu problema é que esta chamada me retorna uma objeto que contem outro objeto, na hora da exibição acontece isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu queria personalizar a coluna [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ab50.png) com nome da Secretaria e não o tipo do objeto

xaml do data grid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgPagamentos" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,177,57,0" Width="557" Height="163" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

código de geração dos dados

```
public static List<Pagamento> ExibirPagamentosPorCliente(int id)
    {
        List<Pagamento> pagamentos = new List<Pagamento>();
        try
        {
            using (ConsultorioContext ctx = new ConsultorioContext())
            {
                pagamentos = ctx.Pagamentos.Where(p => p.Cliente.Id == id).Include(r => r.Recebedor).ToList();

                return pagamentos;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return pagamentos;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mostre o XAML do `dataGrid` e código que gera os dados.

Comment: editei a pergunta, coloquei os dois dados

Comment: Está acontecendo isso porque você está passando o `r.Recebedor` e `Recebedor` deve ser uma classe de alto nível e não campo ou propriedade fundamental.

Comment: Dentro de `Recebedor` deve ter algum campo cujo o nome seja da secretaria? Supondo qu e seja `nomeSecretaria` faça `pagamentos = ctx.Pagamentos.Where(p => p.Cliente.Id == id).Include(r => r.Recebedor.nomeSecretaria).ToList();`

Comment: pagamentos = ctx.Pagamentos.Where(p => p.Cliente.Id == id).Include(r => r.Recebedor.Nome).ToList(); tentei com essa linha porem não surtiu efeito, não me retorno nada

Answer (score 0):

a maneira que consegui corrigir meu problema foi assim

xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgPagamentos" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,177,57,0" Width="557" Height="163" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Recebedor" Binding="{Binding Recebedor.Nome}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Forma de Pagamento" Binding="{Binding FormaDePagamento}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data de Pagamento" Binding="{Binding DataDePagamento}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding Valor}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

consulta ao banco

```
pagamentos = ctx.Pagamentos.Where(p => p.Cliente.Id == id).Include(r => r.Recebedor).ToList();
```